# xunique can not load image when running app

Tags: image, xunique

when I install the conflict solution tool xunique, I found that i works well for merge conflict in project file. when I run app in simulator,the images could not load any more, it happens sometimes, i am afraid of making some mistakes in the future, How could it help

Answer (score 1):

I solve this mistake by delete my images and add it again， i guess that the  images resources before xunique dropped in your project didn't sorted by xunique,so you need add it again